# Visiting Montserrat from St Kitts

Tags: caribbean, day-trips, montserrat

We are going on holiday to St Kitts & Nevis (staying on St Kitts), but we've also been reading a lot recently about Montserrat. Is it possible to visit it on a day trip? They seem close, but all the references I can find suggest going from Antigua - and going St Kitts -> Antigua -> Montserrat and back would be too much for a day trip (and probably too expensive!)

Comment: There don't appear to be any direct flights. Also connecting in Antigua is a 3 hr flight.

Comment: The only scheduled flights to and from MNI (Osborne/Gerald's) are to and from ANU. Consult a travel agent to see if there are charters available from St. Kitt's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Saint-Kitts/Montserrat) suggests the only way is to fly to ANU (Antigua) and then you're needing to get from there to MNI.

That's an hour flying, which immediately pretty much rules out any other transport (obviously can't drive/train, so boat is the only other option and it's too far for a day trip).

Conclusion: you're going to either need to cough up for a charter flight, which won't be cheap, or fly via Antigua, staying overnight at least somewhere enroute or in Montserrat.